# UNTRUSTED_CERT_TITLE trying to install Sierra

Tags: macos, recovery

I'm trying to reinstall macOS Sierra from the recovery partition, and I'm getting an error when it is checking for eligibility [image: This computer is a mac]

The computer that I'm using is most definitely a Mac, and I can't use it until I install Sierra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give an actual set of steps to expand on the answer from Sam

- Go to Utilities -> Terminal
- If connected to Wifi, use ntpdate

  ntpdate time.apple.com
- If not on wifi, use `date` command

  date 1201160419    # Sets date to 4:04PM Dec 1, 2019
- Quit terminal and restart install procedure

Comment: The date command works [month][day][hour][min][year]. For [year] only use the last two digits, for example 2019 would be put in as 19.

Comment: ^ clarity for anyone who doesn't know. Thanks for @JDS for the instructions

Answer (score 0):

I just set the date in terminal using the `date` command, and it is now letting me install macOS Sierra

Comment: Unclear. You just set the date in terminal...and what happened?

Comment: It is now letting me install Sierra

Comment: Which is all good and stuff, but my external hdd connected isn't being recognized so I can't restore from backup

Comment: I set the current date and it worked. Tried with dates which should correlate better to the release of the Sierra version in September of 2016 but that did not go through at all.

Comment: The wifi part worked for me, Thanks man